# In c++, can I have a class which has some functions only under certain conditions?

Tags: c++, methods

I have this code:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int _a, int _b = 0) : a(_a), b(_b) {}
    void f(){}
    #if _b == 0
    void g(){}
    #endif

private:
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    A x(1);
    x.g();

    return 0;
}
```

I want A to have the method g() only if b is 0. I know the code above doesn't work, but I want to know if there is some way of achieving this.

Comment: Can you provide a high level description of the use case? That cannot be done, and without a better description providing alternatives is just blind guessing the intent. Here is a hint: functions are present or not in a type at compile time, and `b` is a runtime value.

Comment: What should happen if you try to do x.g() if b != 0?

Comment: Do you want to get a compile error, or what ?

Comment: @David Rodriguez Let's say I have a class which has an n-dimensional array. If it's vector, I only want to overload the [] operator. If it has more than one dimension, I would have to overload the () operator.

Comment: @conectionist: Is the number of dimensions really a runtime value? You might want to create a template that takes the dimensions and then you can implement `operator()`/`operator[]` for the different specializations.

Comment: @oopsi No. Apparently, in the preprocessing phase, b != 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a template and provide the number of dimensions as a template argument (compile time constant). Then use specialization to provide the different interfaces:

```
class Matrix_base {...};     // common code
template <int Dimensions>
struct Matrix;
template <>
struct Matrix<1> : Matrix_base {
    int operator[]( std::size_t idx ) const {
       // ...
    }
};
template <>
struct Matrix<2> : Matrix_base {
    int operator()( std::size_t idx1, std::size_t idx2 ) const {
       // ...
    }
}
// ...
Matrix<1> v( 10 );
std::cout << v[5];
// v(5,1)                  // error
Matrix<2> m( 10, 20 );
// std::cout << m[5];      // error
std::cout << m(5,1);
```

Answer (score 2):

No. The values are only known at runtime. But you can check values in function and throw a fit.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is impossible. `b` is known only at runtime. I suggest to throw an exception if you call your function and `b`is non-zero.

```
void g()
{
   if(b == 0)
   {
      Exception e("error..."); // Your exception class or a std::exception class
      throw e;
   }

   // The code from here will not be executed
}
```